Can using AR Core at hight speed cause problems?
I want to make an augmented reality app using AR Core. There are multiple possibilities for my app but here is the main two:

You will input a list a GPS Coordinates that will be placed as anchors.Then the phone will be placed on top of bike to film to road ahead. Finally, a 3d model will be rendered in real time, moving between positions.This will use the Geospatial API.

The phone will be placed the same, but rather then placing anchors we will be using the Scene Semantics API to understand the environment and render the moving 3d model accordingly.


So one app base the 3d object movements on GPS coordinates and the other on environment understanding.
I was wondering if the fact that my app will be mounted on a bike and therefore have to film the road at speeds like 50 or 60 km/h can cause problems with the use of AR Core.

No.  GPS is able to keep up with cars, a bike won't be any problem.  All ARCore really does is map GPS coordinates to relative camera coordinates.  Now you will have drift issues due to GPS inaccuracy and similar issues, but you'll have that even stationary.
